# at / on/ in (the) (Math) exam

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, transatlantic-differences, in-on

I think it is common to say

> I did well **on** the exam in AmE.
>
> I did well **in** the exam in BrE.

Which prepositions are suitable for the following situations when we mention the exam we took? Regarding that, how are they used differently in American and British English? And do we need to use article *the*?

> I did well on/in/at (the) Math exam.
>
> I did well on/in/at the presentation.

Comment: [*...did well **on** the exam*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+well+in+the+exam%2Cdid+well+on+the+exam%2Cdid+well+at+the+exam%2Cdid+well+with+the+exam&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20well%20in%20the%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20well%20on%20the%20exam%3B%2Cc0) is certainly more common, but notions of "correctness" here are really just subjective opinions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks. Is it "correct" for the Math exam ?

Comment: People often get mixed up re AmE and BrE. In many cases, there is no difference at all. This is one of them. To do well ON the exam. No at here for either one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did well *on* the exam? In Britain? It sounds quite foreign to me. I would have said we always used *in the exam*. The only exception to that I would suggest would be if it were some kind of oral, or performance exam - e.g a driving test, when you might say *I was much better **on** the test*.

Comment: @WS2: There's a [significant US/UK split here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+exam%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Con+the+exam%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cin+the+exam%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+the+exam%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20exam%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20exam%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20exam%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20exam%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0). Like you (and most Brits), I'd normally use ***in*** - but it's just idiomatic preference, not a matter of "grammatically correct".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Anyone British training to pass themselves off as American, or vice-versa, would have to concentrate very heavily on prepositions. An *on* or an *in* could easily betray you, in my estimation.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, may I paraphrase your question(s): 
"Which preposition *is* suitable *when* mentioning an exam I took, how *come* the preposition *is* different in American *to that of* British English, and *last but not least*, do I need to use *the definite* article ('the') in *either* sentence?"

Final question first:  Yes, you need 'the' if you want to indicate a specific exam (**even** in the understood context).

Why American English is different from English English? 
I would argue that they like to express their differences (and that includes spelling and prepositions).  But the logic is the real determiner:  If Americans say 'on the weekend' it's most probably because they're in the habit of working on either Saturday or Sunday, so they only really count the weekend as *one day*. Then, it just stuck (even if some do have two days off.)

Which brings us to AT (one of your options). AT is used for events (on more than one day), places and time. 
I would not use AT in your example unless you were only (doing something other than sitting the actual exam in that same location and at the time of the exam). 
Another point is that we **are** GOOD or BAD **at** something, in general. 
But we don't "**do** well" **at** something.

As for **on** or **in**, I'd personally go for **on**. 
After all, there's an expression: to SIT an exam.

Comment: I'm sorry. We Americans don't use different prepositions  to "express our differences". Maybe that's partly why Webster's spelling reform caught on, but we stopped caring about showing that we're different from Brits around 150 years ago. We use different prepositions because ***that's the way we speak.*** Why do modern Brits speak differently than Shakespeare did?